# gyp ERR! find VS gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use gyp

Tags: yarn-v2

I tried to run yarn, and it gives me:

```
$ yarn yarn install v1.22.19 [1/5] Validating package.json... [2/5] Resolving packages... [3/5] Fetching packages... [4/5] Linking dependencies... warning " > eslint-loader@4.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0". warning " > eslint-loader@4.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0". warning "netlify-cli > @netlify/build > ts-node@10.9.1" has unmet peer dependency "@types/node@*". warning "netlify-cli > @netlify/build > @honeycombio/opentelemetry-node > @opentelemetry/sdk-node@0.36.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@opentelemetry/api@>=1.3.0 <1.5.0". warning "netlify-cli > @netlify/build > @honeycombio/opentelemetry-node > @opentelemetry/exporter-metrics-otlp-grpc > @opentelemetry/core@1.10.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@opentelemetry/api@>=1.0.0 <1.5.0". warning "netlify-cli > @netlify/build > @honeycombio/opentelemetry-node > @opentelemetry/exporter-metrics-otlp-grpc > @opentelemetry/otlp-transformer@0.36.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@opentelemetry/api@>=1.3.0 <1.5.0". warning "netlify-cli > @netlify/build > @honeycombio/opentelemetry-node > @opentelemetry/exporter-metrics-otlp-grpc > @opentelemetry/resources@1.10.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@opentelemetry/api@>=1.0.0 <1.5.0". warning "netlify-cli > @netlify/build > @honeycombio/opentelemetry-node > @opentelemetry/exporter-metrics-otlp-grpc > @opentelemetry/sdk-metrics@1.10.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@opentelemetry/api@>=1.3.0 <1.5.0". warning "netlify-cli > @netlify/build > @honeycombio/opentelemetry-node > @opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-grpc > @opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base@1.10.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@opentelemetry/api@>=1.0.0 <1.5.0". warning "netlify-cli > @netlify/build > @honeycombio/opentelemetry-node > @opentelemetry/sdk-node > @opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node@1.10.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@opentelemetry/api@>=1.0.0 <1.5.0". warning "netlify-cli > @netlify/build > @honeycombio/opentelemetry-node > @opentelemetry/sdk-node > @opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node > @opentelemetry/context-async-hooks@1.10.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@opentelemetry/api@>=1.0.0 <1.5.0". warning "netlify-cli > @netlify/build > @honeycombio/opentelemetry-node > @opentelemetry/sdk-node > @opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node > @opentelemetry/propagator-b3@1.10.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@opentelemetry/api@>=1.0.0 <1.5.0". warning "netlify-cli > @netlify/build > @honeycombio/opentelemetry-node > @opentelemetry/sdk-node > @opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node > @opentelemetry/propagator-jaeger@1.10.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@opentelemetry/api@>=1.0.0 <1.5.0". warning "workspace-aggregator > website > @deck.gl/layers@8.9.32" has unmet peer dependency "@loaders.gl/core@^3.4.13". warning "workspace-aggregator > website > @deck.gl/layers@8.9.32" has unmet peer dependency "@luma.gl/core@^8.0.0". warning "workspace-aggregator > website > sass-loader@12.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^5.0.0". warning "workspace-aggregator > website > vue-gtag@1.16.1" has incorrect peer dependency "vue@^2.0.0". warning "workspace-aggregator
> website > bootstrap-vue > bootstrap@4.6.2" has unmet peer dependency "jquery@1.9.1 - 3". warning "workspace-aggregator > website > bootstrap-vue > portal-vue@2.1.7" has incorrect peer dependency "vue@^2.5.18". [5/5] Building fresh packages... warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "C:\\path\\to\\project\\node_modules\\unix-dgram: Command failed. Exit code: 1 Command: node-gyp rebuild Arguments: Directory: C:\\path\\to\\project\\node_modules\\unix-dgram Output: C:\\path\\to\\project\\node_modules\\unix-dgram>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node \"C:\\path\\to\\.nvm\\versions\\node\\v18.19.0\\bin\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\node-gyp-bin\\\\..\\..\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js\" rebuild )  else (node \"\" rebuild ) gyp info it worked if it ends with ok gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1 gyp info using node@18.19.0 | win32 | x64 gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.6 found at \"C:\\path\\to\\Python310\\python.exe\"  gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.19.0/node-v18.19.0-headers.tar.gz gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.19.0/node-v18.19.0-headers.tar.gz gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.19.0/SHASUMS256.txt gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.19.0/win-x64/node.lib gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.19.0/SHASUMS256.txt gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.19.0/win-x64/node.lib gyp ERR! find VS gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015 gyp ERR! find VS - not found gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8 gyp ERR! find VS gyp ERR! find VS
************************************************************** gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio gyp ERR! find VS including the \"Desktop development with C++\" workload. gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at: gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows gyp ERR! find VS
************************************************************** gyp ERR! find VS gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use gyp ERR! stack at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\\path\\to\\.nvm\\versions\\node\\v18.19.0\\bin\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\lib\\find-visualstudio.js:113:11) gyp ERR! stack at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio (C:\\path\\to\\.nvm\\versions\\node\\v18.19.0\\bin\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\lib\\find-visualstudio.js:69:17) gyp ERR! stack at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) gyp ERR! stack at async createBuildDir (C:\\path\\to\\.nvm\\versions\\node\\v18.19.0\\bin\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\lib\\configure.js:69:26) gyp ERR! stack at async run (C:\\path\\to\\.nvm\\versions\\node\\v18.19.0\\bin\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js:81:18) gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041 gyp ERR! command \"C:\\path\\to\\.nvm\\versions\\node\\v18.19.0\\bin\\node.exe\" \"C:\\path\\to\\.nvm\\versions\\node\\v18.19.0\\bin\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js\" \"rebuild\" gyp ERR! cwd C:\\path\\to\\project\\node_modules\\unix-dgram gyp ERR! node -v v18.19.0 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.0.1 gyp ERR! not ok" info This module is OPTIONAL, you can safely ignore this error Done in 269.25s.
```

https://github.com/MobilityData/gbfs-validator

Tried to follow the instructions using nvm use 18 and install it via yarn, but it gave me that error.

Also, for the second step.

> ```
> Connect your local project to the gbfs-validator Netlify site to access its environment variables
> ```
>
> netlify link**strong text**

Does it refer to the netlify installed inside the repo meaning you can run the app without having a netlify website to consume it?